# CMD in Windows 7 does not execute command (Python Django)

Tags: python, django, cmd

Ok people at this [link](https://github.com/lukerosiak/pysec/issues/11) for pysec as the technical solution is explained we have some code that you must type to the command prompt (i think because it has a dollar sign in front):

```
$ cd ~/path/to/pysec && python -c "import sqlite3; sqlite3.connect('edgar.db')"
$ mv ./local-settings-example.py ./local-settings.py
$ mkdir ./pysec/data
```

However whenever i go to `C:\Python27\pysec-master` which is the location where the pysec file is stored (according to instructions) and type these commands exactly as i see them i get that `the system cannot find the path specified.`

Like this

```
C:\Python27\pysec-master>cd ~/path/to/pysec && python -c
cmd response --> The system cannot find the path specified.

C:\Python27\pysec-master>cd ~/path/to/pysec && python -c "import sqlite3; sqlite3.connect('edgar.db')"
cmd response --> The system cannot find the path specified.

C:\Python27\pysec-master>mv ./local-settings-example.py ./local-settings.py
cmd response --> 'mv' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

C:\Python27\pysec-master>mkdir ./pysec/data
cmd response --> The syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

What seems to be the problem? Don't you have to type these commands in the `cmd` since they have a dollar sign?

Comment: `cd ~...`, `mv .\` and `mkdir .\ looks more like unix syntax than windows-cmd. `cd` and `mkdir` work on both platforms, but with different syntax. The cmd-version of `mv` is `move`.

Comment: also `/path/to/pysec` tells you, that you should put in the path to pysec, not the string "\path\to\pysec"

Comment: Can we transform these commands to Windows syntax?

Comment: Ohhh yes path\to\pysec !!!!!

Comment: Shoule we put the path to pysec like this: `C:\Python27\pysec-master` i mean the full or absolute as it is called path? Because it that tutorial I can see that the example is trimmed as cd ~/path/to/pysec`

Comment: the tilde (~) has a special meaning in unix. I don't speak unix, but I think it means "Systemdrive". The CMD command would be: `cd /d "c:\Python27\pysec-master"` (in CMD use \, in unix it's /). Instead of `mv` use `move`

Comment: Only the third command does not seem to work `mkdir ./pysec/data` well I think there muse be something different for windows

Comment: `mkdir .\pysec\data` ... You remember?  "in CMD use \, in unix it's /".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ANSWER FOR THIS QUESTION IS PROVIDED FROM THE COMMENTS UNDER THE QUESTION BY USER [Stephan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2152082/stephan)**

I decided to put the all together in on place>

1. cd ~..., mv .` and mkdir .\ looks more like unix syntax than windows-cmd. cd and mkdir work on both platforms, but with different syntax. The cmd-version of mv is move.**(ANSWER)**
2. also /path/to/pysec tells you, that you should put in the path to pysec, not the string "\path\to\pysec"**(ANSWER)**
3. Can we transform these commands to Windows syntax?**(QUESTION)**
4. Should we put the path to pysec like this: C:\Python27\pysec-master i mean the full or absolute as it is called path? Because it that tutorial I can see that the example is trimmed as cd ~/path/to/pysec`**(QUESTION)**
5. the tilde (~) has a special meaning in unix. I don't speak unix, but I think it means "Systemdrive". The CMD command would be: cd /d "c:\Python27\pysec-master" (in CMD use \, in unix it's /). Instead of mv use move **(ANSWER)**
6. Only the third command does not seem to work mkdir ./pysec/data well I think there muse be something different for windows **(QUESTION)**
7. mkdir .\pysec\data ... You remember? "in CMD use \, in unix it's /"**(ANSWER)**

THANK YOU FOR THE SUPPORT

Comment: You're welcome. Please accept your answer, so that everyone can see, that this question has been answered.

Comment: Thank you Stephan. I can accept it according to time in 4 hours. I will do so when the timer allows me.